# Error "no supported WSMan client library was found." with macOS pwsh

Tags: macos, powershell, openssl, wsman

From macOS Terminal, when I execute:

```
pwsh -command "Enter-PSSession myhost"
```

I get error from PowerShell:

```
Enter-PSSession: This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client
library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.
```

I've spent 2 hours to find a solution. I am going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name PSWSMan'
sudo pwsh -Command 'Install-WSMan'
```

Comment: both commands ran and I still get the error.. I'm on armbian bullseye on arm32v7 cpu

Answer (score 16):

See from Matt Thornton: [Exchange Online Powershell on macOS](https://www.matt-thornton.net/general/exchange-online-powershell-on-macos)

Tested below on MacOS 11.6

1. `brew install powershell`
2. `brew install openssl`
3. `pwsh`
4. `Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet`
5. `Install-Module -Name PSWSMan`
6. `sudo pwsh -Command 'Install-WSMan'`

Answer (score 8):

This followings work on Mac without issue.

```
pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name PSWSMan'

sudo pwsh -Command 'Install-WSMan'
```

Answer (score 4):

Root cause of the issue is Powershell dependency to previous openssl version. It is apparently not easy to fix according to GitHub issue [PowerShell/#5561](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5561).

Here is the workaround I have found:

```
curl -L https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb \
  -o openssl.rb
brew install ./openssl.rb
```

Comment: Is this still the solution? Im on Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.3
OS                             Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM…
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Comment: @jes516 No, it's a good error message about the module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792872/434034