# Running Powershell script through MacOs Visual Studio Code on remote Windows computer throws MI_RESULT_FAILED

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, visual-studio-code, ntlm

I am attempting to run & debug a Powershell script (which is tailored to run on a remote Windows PC), on MacOS (Monterey M1) through Visual Studio Code.

Mac

```
Name Value
---- -----
PSVersion 7.2.1
PSEdition Core
GitCommitId 7.2.1
OS Darwin 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:28:41 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.6…
Platform Unix
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion 3.0
```

PC

```
 Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

On the Mac, I have installed `PSWSMan` and following this article https://petri.com/how-to-run-code-remotely-in-visual-studio-code I have attempted to initiate the remote session using:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName '192.168.1.185' -Credential xxx
```

The system throws this error right after the password input:

```
Enter-PSSession: Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.185 failed with the following error message : MI_RESULT_FAILED For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

which could be due to NTLM incompatibility: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/887

Anyone successfully running this scenario?

Comment: Any chance you were are to resolve this issue. I am running into the exact same issue with PS 7.3.3 on MacOS.

Comment: No, I have abandoned this.... Curious to know if you can spot it out

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the MI_RESULT_FAILED issue, **try using the full UPN for the credential.**

Our systems are on a domain (my M1-based Mac is *not* on the domain). Our corporate internal AD domain is formatted like so: `DOMAIN.LOCAL` (as opposed to domain.com, or our alternate domain emaildomain.com that we use for email and Azure logins). I am able to successfully remote into a Windows-based computer named MYPC01 using the following:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MYPC01 -Credential username@domain.local
```

The screenshot below is of my successful connection to our domain controller from my Mac:

[image: Screenshot of successful PowerShell connection from Mac to PC]

Type `exit` to exit the session and return to your local PS session in your Mac's terminal.

---

For reference, below is the output from my Mac's PowerShell installation:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.4
OS                             Darwin 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:41 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/…
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

---

NOTE: You must already have [WSMan installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792872/751220), *which may require re-installation after updating PowerShell on macOS*.

```
pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name PSWSMan'
sudo pwsh -Command 'Install-WSMan'
```